# Datatables Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to access the value of a datatables cell using

```
 console.log(table.Rows[1][12]);
```

But I get the error "Datatables Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

I verify that the data is rendering and available using

```
 $('#datatable_tabletools').DataTable().row(1).columns(12).data()
```

In the console, I try

```
 $('#datatable_tabletools').DataTable().Rows[1][12]
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Why am I not able to access the value of the a cell?

Comment: Why not just use `$('#datatable_tabletools').DataTable().row(1).columns(12).data()`?

Comment: That was bringing back an array of all rows rather than the 1 row as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar issues, I ended up using

```
 $('#datatable_tabletools').DataTable().columns(12).data()[0][row]
```

where row is defined by an enclosing loop.